# Konva.js - how to get the position of an object that is in a group, measured within its layer?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

1. When I use

`layer.findOne('#'+mynode).x()`

this gives me the X position of the mynode, but only when mynode is ungrouped. If I group it, then it is not updated when the group is dragged.

2. When I use

`absolutePosition()`

method for a node - it works (returning the realtime position of a node), but only to the point when the view is moved or zoomed. Then the layer coordinates are no longer aligned with the absolute coordinates, so when I draw a line between nodes on the layer using those absolute coordinates, the line does not stick to the nodes.

So, how to get the position of an object that is in a group, but measured within its layer - so that I can use them to draw a line between nodes on that layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `node.getAbsolutePosition(layer)`. That function will return the absolute position of the node relative to the passed container (layer).